# 'Spark' CiviCRM on a shared server?

Tags: hosting, civicrm-spark

Our new webhost will not permit us to use CiviCRM on its server due to use of 'triggers' and their unwillingness to grant us 'superuser' admin status. Will the lite version of CiviCRM that is coming out in February (Spark I think) be more acceptable to hosts who use shared servers for tiny not-for-profit organisations? We were using CiviCRM with Wordpress under our previous shared hosting arrangement without any problems but had to change hosts for security reasons and have found that it is no longer compatible in shared hosting environments. Is separate dedicated CiviCRM hosting our only future option?
Karen

Comment: Could you specify where you found the information that there should be a "lite" version of CiviCRM? That would be news...

Comment: My understanding is that Spark is going to be a hosted SaaS by the CiviCRM core team - it's not a self-hosted solution.

Comment: I swear I read about this today but I can't find the article anymore!

Comment: Also - you should use another host.  Plenty of good hosts out there - if you want to support the community there are a bunch of specialized hosts.  TMDHosting is like other traditional shared hosts (CPanel) that is a supporting partner and CiviHosting is a specialized shared host (alternative control panel and approach) that is also a supporting partner.

Comment: The news about CiviCRM 'Spark' comes from the CiviCRM News mailing of 3rd January, to quote "2. Introduction of CiviCRM “Spark”, a lightweight, hosted version of CiviCRM intended to onboard new potential users quickly. Look for a launch in February."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CiviCRM is compatible with shared hosting. It always has been. The host needs to support the server-side features that CiviCRM requires, however, and not all do.

There is a page on the CiviCRM site here: https://civicrm.org/hosting-providers with a list of such hosts, and most of the hosts there have shared hosting.

Comment: I will be interested to see what the 'Spark' hosted package can provide as we have only been using a few of the features that CiviCRM makes available and this may be the most efficient way forward for us.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need superuser status to use triggers on modern versions of MySQL (5.5+).  Of course, your host may just choose not to support triggers, in which case they're unsuitable for hosting CiviCRM.

Comment: Yes, we were on a shared hosting arrangement before and they had no problems with CiviCRM but unfortunately they were also rubbish at providing a secure environment for our site and data! We are a tiny charity so do not have funds for paid hosting and need to get the best features for our 'free' hosting that we can find.

Answer (score 2):

You could decide to move to a specialized CiviCRM hoster? You can find some on the list here: https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors?country=All&services=Hosting&language=All&cms=All

Comment: I have been looking in to that too. Our issue is the need to have UK hosting with the new Data Protection Legislation that comes in to force in May of this year. There are a number of UK consultants willing to assist with set up etc but really I just need it hosted, and that gives me just a few options. Definitely something we are looking in to.